# Difference between the use of pointers for array and single data point?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAX = 3;

int main ()
{
   int  var[MAX] = {10, 100, 200};
   int  *ptr;

   // let us have array address in pointer.
  ptr = var;
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
   {
      cout << "Address of var[" << i << "] = ";
      cout << ptr << endl;

      cout << "Value of var[" << i << "] = ";
      cout << *ptr << endl;

      // point to the next location
      ptr++;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why this code should work as the correct syntax is

```
ptr=&var[0];
```

instead of

```
ptr=var;
```

if var would have been something like

```
int var=49;
```

then the my version of reasoning holds and earlier program fails. Is their any distinct concept of pointer for array and single data point?

Comment: The name of an array decays into the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4810668/27678

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we should understand that pointers and arrays are handled the same in C or C++, at least once we've moved past the definition. Let's make sure we understand a few things. From the example you have described above, the following are equivalent (after ptr=var).

var[0], *var, ptr[0], ptr. All == 10.

In the case of:

```
ptr = &var[0];
```

That is assigning the address of the first element of var. Another way to say that is that &var is a pointer to a pointer to an int. We know that var is a pointer to an int (int *) and *var is an int.

If *var and var[0] are equivalent, then we're doing the equivalent of *(&var), which is just var.

Maybe to make this more clear, you could think about a different index than 0. var[1] is the same as (var + 1). It holds then that:

```
ptr = var + 1
```

is the same as

```
ptr = &var[1]
```

They're just two different ways to express the same thing.

In your example of int var=49, var is an int, not a pointer to an int (remember that an array is just a pointer, so pointer to an int is the same as an array of ints). You could express that as:

```
int var=49;
ptr = &var;
```

Then if you remove the loop (or set MAX=1) you'll get the result you're looking for.

Think of * as removing a level of addressing (pointers) and & as adding one. It's a little confusing because * does the opposite when you're defining them.

```
int **i;
```

Means a pointer to a pointer of an int. Then:

&i - pointer to a pointer to a pointer of an int.
i  - pointer to a pointer of an int.
*i - pointer to an int
**i - int
i[0] - pointer of an int
*i[0] - int

Pointers in C and C++ are simply another datatype. The question of "Is their any distinct concept of pointer for array and single data point?" is a bit flawed because in your example you have an array (which is equivalent to a pointer), not an array to a pointer. A single data point (in your second example int var=49) still has an address, but isn't an array, so it isn't a pointer type, it is an integer type. You could have easily described that as:

```
int var[1] = {49};
```

Which is an array (pointer) to a single int, which should not be confused with an int.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't understand why this code should work as the correct syntax is
>
> ```
> ptr=&var[0];
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> ptr=var;
> ```

The two ways of assigning a pointer are equivalent. In expressions that assign an array variable to a pointer C++ interprets the array name as a pointer to the initial element of the array, i.e. `&var[0]`.

> If var would have been something like
>
> ```
> int var=49;
> ```
>
> then the my version of reasoning holds and earlier program fails.

This is because C++ provides an implicit conversion to pointer from arrays, but not from scalar variables.

Answer (score -1):

An array name holds the address of its first element in memory. i.e a pointer.

```
int array[2] = {1,2}; // "array" is a pointer to array[0]
int **p = &array;  //pointer to pointer to array[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

The name of array is a `reference` to first index of array. 
The correct way of assigning a `pointer` to array is:

```
int *ptr = arrayName;
```

**OR**

```
int *ptr = &arrayName[0];
```

An other thing to keep in mind is that you can add offset to pointer to reference other elements of array. This will point to the first value of aray `*ptr++;` OR `*ptr+=1;`. Whereas doing this with variable pointer will yield unexpected results.